# Pip package not found after successful installation

Tags: python, path, pip

I ran  `pip3 install detect-secrets`; but running  `detect-secrets` then gives "Command not found".

I also tried variations, for example the switch  `--user`; `sudo`; and even  `pip` rather than `pip3`. Also with underscore in the name.

I further added all directories shown in  `python3.6 -m site` to my `PATH` (Ubuntu 18.04).

Retrying the installation command  shows that  the package was successfully installed.

`find . -name detect-secrets` (also `detect_secrets`)  shows these in `./.local/bin/detect-secrets` and `./home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/detect_secrets`)

None of these gave access to the  executable. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `pip3 install detect_secrets`, with the underline, do this from the root `/`:

`sudo find . -name detect-secrets 2>/dev/null`.

You may find a result in it in   `/.local/bin/` or in `/home/user/.local/bin/detect-secrets` (strangely, that's even if you do not use the `--user` switch on `pip3 install`).

Add this directory to the path with `PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.local/bin/`.

Now  `detect-secrets`, with the dash, works.

Comment: Loos good, but does not show the actual path. When run from root dir, it gives  Location: /home/user /.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages. But Setting PATH to that does not work. It seems that /home/user/.local/bin/ receives an executable file which is actually a Python script that references the Python files in   /home/user /.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: How can I set it for windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try executing:

```
which pip3
```

To know exactly which pip are you executing. You can do the same for python3 although it should also point you to the same python. This might help you detect what is the issue

Comment: $ which pip3 gives /usr/bin/pip3

Comment: Also, pip3 list does include  detect_secrets.

So the question is -- why does the command detect_secrets not work? some sort of PATH issue?

Comment: i believe the package is installed you are just not executing it properly. I faced the same issue as you but try executing:
`detect-secrets audit --help`

to know the options of the command

Comment: I would say that the package installed but not being found at all  when I invoke it. The  command `detect-secrets audit --help` gives `detect-secrets: command not found`

Comment: Are you running:
`detect_secrets`
or
`detect-secrets`?
The first one is the library name and the second one the command name.